# What is the meaning of symmetric modulo?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

So I was reading this: http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/a-new-factoring-algorithm/

and found it saying "symmetic modulo"

So first off: what is "  a  -special matrix provided the following are true:" (refer to link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$A$ is symmetric modulo $n$" means that $A$ and $A^t$ are congruent modulo $n$.

Comment: does that mean that two numbers $a$ and $b$ are the same after a modulo operation by n? Ex. 23 and 19 are congruent mod 4. Is this what congruent means? Equal remainders after a modulo as I believe is defined [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modulus)

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you very much. What would be the utility of this though? Number theory and primality are all I can think of. Do you know of any practical applications?

Comment: Well, apparently it's at least useful for cooking up April Fools' pranks... ;-)

Comment: besides April Fools?

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to look at the date on the blog.  And perhaps at the somewhat unusual name of the originator of the algorithm.